# Cookie less Session not expires after closing IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, c#-4.0

I change my sessions setting in web config:

```
 <sessionState cookieless="true" timeout="20" mode="InProc" />
```

and when I copy my address and close IE and then I enter address in another IE instance session not expires. What can I do for expiring session after IE closed?

thanks

---

**Edit 1)**

Does this problem related to `cookieless` settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

The session identity is in the URL, not in the browser. When you copy the URL, you also copy the session identity, and closing the browser doesn't change the URL that you copied.

Comment: @Kerezo: Yes. Then the session identity will be stored in a session cookie in the browser, and goes away when you close the browser. (This of course requires that the user haven't blocked session cookies in the browser.)

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** clear the session. This information is stored on the server.
However, you might want to check this link: [LINK](http://forums.asp.net/t/1594193.aspx/1)

You might see what you want. Hope it helps.